# Difference between String Literal and Identifier in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

What's the difference between a string literal and an identifier? I tried googling this and ended up being more confused

Specifically interested with the difference in Python, and difference in SQLite

From SQLite Documentation

```
'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
"keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
```

Reference Documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Let's back up and figure out where you are on definitions. Do you know what a "string literal" is, in the general/theoretical/language-agnostic sense? Do you know what an identifier is?

Comment: BTW, SQLite's behavior here follows that of SQL in general; there's nothing specific to the library.

Comment: I don't know the basics unfortunately. Trying to learn here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An identifier is a variable name. In the following python line

```
foo = "bar"
```

`foo` is an identifier and "bar" is a string literal. In Python, string literal can be enclosed in simple (`'`') or double (`"`) quotes.

In SQLite (and more generally in SQL), string literals are enclosed in single quotes. Double quotes are use to force a string containing otherwise special characters to be interpreted as identifiers.

Example assuming a table `foo` with column `bar` :

```
SELECT bar as "Bar", 'zz' as OTHER from foo;
```

In this select, the first column will have name `Bar`. Without the `"`, the name would have been `bar` since SQL does not normally distinguishes case. The second column will the the constant `zz` and the column name will be `other`.

The `"` are also useful to have accented chars like `éè` for non english languages.

Comment: SQLite does not have variables; please mention table/column names.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in this answer, though it is very good. 

In Python, the double quotes indicate a string literal. But in SQLite, the *single* quotes indicate a string literal while double quotes are an identifier. So in your SQL SELECT statement I think "Bar" would be the value of whatever the identifier Bar is, while the 'zz' column would be literally named 'zz'.

Comment: Also as per @CL. , there aren't variables in SQLite anyways, so "Bar" would have to reference either a table or a column name.

Comment: I think according to [this link](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html) under heading #8, there are certain circumstances that double quotes can be used to indicate a string literal in SQLite, but it highly not recommended to use this fact. It seems to be more of a historical feature that they have kept for compatibility.

Comment: See [this link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) for single quotes vs double quotes in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

In Python both 'keyword' and "keyword" are just string literals, no difference.

In SQLite, if you want to use a SQLite keyword (not a Python keyword) as a string literal (so a value of a string) you should use ''. If you want to use it as a SQLite identifier, e.g. a table name, you have to use "".

Comment: Good as far as it goes, but doesn't cover the cases exhaustively at present; should probably be extended to be explicit about unquoted words in both languages and to provide examples.

Comment: So I can run query on a table without needing to put the table name in quotes. As I understand it a table name is an identifier, so sometimes identifiers don't require quotes?

Comment: @canyon289, correct; it's only if you want to preserve case, or use a name that otherwise wouldn't be valid, that quotes are needed for identifiers (such as table or column names) in SQL.